# LINQ join issue on trying to join 2 tables form entity framwork

Tags: linq

```
[DimAccount]         [FactFinance]
```

The 2 tables above are getting from AdventureWorksDW2008 database.

I am trying to do a left join, for some reason it give me error.  I've done this successfully on tables that don't have Foreign Key.  Here is code and the errors.  Any idea how to resolve the issue?

```
 Dim result = From q In da.DimAccount _
              Group Join p In da.FactFinance On p.AccountKey Equals q.AccountKey Into x = Group _
              From p In x.DefaultIfEmpty _
              Select New AccountInfo With { _
                            .AccountKey = q.AccountKey, _
                            .AccountDesc = q.AccountDescription, _
                            .Amount = p.Amount _
                         }
```

Here is the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WindowsApplication1.FactFinance] DefaultIfEmpty[FactFinance](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WindowsApplication1.FactFinance])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Group by is NOT used for Left Joins.

Comment: I think i know what the issue is  .DefaultIfEmpty() doesn't support in .Net 3.5